# Unable to fetch the data for the multiple stocks from the nsepy by using python

Tags: python, nsepy

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,date,time,timedelta
from nsepy import get_history

stocks = ['JSWSTEEL','RELIANCE','AXISBANK','HCLTECH','TECHM']
start = datetime.today() - timedelta(365)
end = datetime.today()
close_price = pd.DataFrame()

for tickers in stocks:
    close_price[tickers] = get_history(tickers,start,end)
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>
> ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series

kindly help me in above code to get information for multiple stocks

Thanks

Comment: Is that the entire error output? Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

---

**Solution 1**:
Replace `close_price[tickers] = get_history(tickers,start,end)` with `close_price[tickers] = get_history(tickers,start,end)['Close']`.

---

**Solution 2**:
Replace `close_price = pd.DataFrame()` with `close_price = {}`.

---

***Explanation:***

This error is coming because you have defined 'close_price' as a Dataframe which is not the case.
As the get_history function, itself returns a pandas DataFrame so in the below line

```
close_price[tickers] = get_history(tickers,start,end)
```

you are actually assigning a data frame to a column of close_price. As 2-D dataframe (returned by get_history) can not be converted into a Series, hence the error.

So you can simply define close_price as a dictionary instead of dataframe

or

extract Close price series from the returned dataframe, extract close price from it and assign it to your defined dataframe ( which is what you are trying to do).